# Web Api Get() route not working when return type is HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is causing me a bit of a headache. Ultimately, I'm trying to return an image but I've been experimenting and simplified this to using  a string.

What I want:
go to URL:

```
http://xxx/api/helloworld/1
```

Responds with: "Hello world!"

The following web api declarations work for the url supplied;

```
public string Get([FromUri]int id) { return "Hello World"; }
public Task<string> Get([FromUri]int id) { return "Hello World"; }
```

What does NOT work;

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]int id) 
{ 
    return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello World");
}

public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]int id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    string text = "Hello World";
    MemoryStream test = new MemoryStream();
    test.Write(ConversionUtilities.ToBytes(text) /*custom string->byte[] method, UTF-8 encoding*/, 0, text.Length);

    response.Content = new StreamContent(test);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

    return response;
}
```

What happens when I have a Get() with a return type of HttpResponseMessage is the following error is returned;

```
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI "http://xxx/api/helloworld/1"
```

This error only appears for this particular return type. Now, my routing in the WebApiConfig.cs file is as follows (and works for "string" return types);

```
// Controller with ID
// To handle routes like "/api/VTRouting/1"
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerAndId",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers 
);

// Controllers with Actions
// To handle routes like "/api/VTRouting/route"
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerAndAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
);

// Controller Only
// To handle routes like "/api/VTRouting"
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerOnly",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);
```

Any thoughts? I'm stumped as to the return type behaviour :-S

Comment: Is your controller name HelloWorld?

Comment: for the purposes of the sample code, yes. An ApiController of called HelloWorldController should work with the samples above

Comment: how do you have two actions on the same controller called "Get" with the same parameters? Have you tried calling the Web API from the local machine or setting config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy to Always. You might get better error information.

Comment: There are three ways as per my knowledge . Either you differentiate via parameter names , Create your actions by action name attribute (only for methods not starting with Get) , or by different Method Names like Get1 and Get2 and use them directly in your uri like api/mycontroller/Get1 .

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work either. I get the same "resource not found" response now for return types "string" and "HttpResponseMessage". I've done a bit more tweaking and if the routing was (completely) incorrect, IIS would return an IIS resource error. The error message specified in my post seems to come from the web-api routing mechanism where it interprets the URL correctly but cannot find the correct method to call. Possibly impling that the routing configuration needs to specify the HttpResponseMessage return type?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your scenario. I used the same routes and actions as above.

Comment: I'm actually in the process of doing this myself on my machine at home. So far the code above works in vs2012. I'm downloading the mvc 4 pack for vs2010 sp1 now to see if the issue is there. The installation I'm using is based on vs2010. I'll post again here if I've verified the issue or not

Comment: Vexing. Cannot replicate on a basic mvc 4 web api template on either vs2010 or vs2012. Code and routing as above but they work just fine. Issue must be with the specific configuration on my machine but I cannot think of anything else that would affect the routing resolution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the cause! I had created a blank api controller as per the template which worked. Cue a bit of copy/pasting to narrow down the cause. It's subtle and the code that I posted worked because I changed the variable names for posting publicly - which was ultimately the cause of the issue. Go figure.

To replicate, create your template as per normal. This will create a method;

```
public string Get(int id)
```

Change this to;

```
public string Get(int personID)
```

And try to run. You'll get the error described as above. It seems that the declaration of the Get/Post/etc parameters MUST match that specified in the routing. If you change the parameter to "personID" as I did, you can fix by either renaming your parameter back to the default "id" or modifying your routing with the updating name;

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerAndId",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{personID}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { personID = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers 
);
```

Note the "{personID}" in the routeTemplate and constraint parameters. The name of this field MUST match that of the name of your parameter. It never actually says this in the doc when looking up how to download files or just generally looking at web api. It probably does when going into a high level of detail on routing/mvc but I have to say that this easily trips up a n00b not familiar with either. Mind you, my more experienced collegues didn't spot this either :-). I hope this helps others with the same pain!

Comment: Yes, it must match the route defined. How else would it assign values to the method parameters?

Comment: @MEMark - positionally is one option.