# c# API Controller passing paramters client.GetAsync error 404

Tags: c#, httpclient, http-get, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a `API Controller` with a Method that recieve a parameter. When I call it from the `client`, get an `404 error`. If a re-write de method with ni parameter it works.

Here is my `API controller`:

```
 public class ClientController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public List<User> GetAAA(int userCode)
        {
           return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is my Client...

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                List<User> list;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                string uriString = string.Format("{0}/{1}", "http://localhost:7734/api/Client/GetAAA", 1783);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uriString);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    list = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<User>>().Result;
                else
                    throw new Exception("Error");
            }
```

Even if I write in navigator `http://localhost:7734/api/Client/GetAAA/1783` it says "Page not found".

My `WebApiConfig` is like this:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Client is misspelled in that url?

Comment: OK it is http://localhost:7734/api/Client/GetAAA/1783 ??

Comment: Your url path segment needs to match the name of the controller exactly.

Since your controller is named ClientController your url needs to be /api/Client/

Comment: yes I worte it bad to this example. if I create a method with zero parameters, it Works....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web Api Get() route not working when return type is HttpResponseMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857370/web-api-get-route-not-working-when-return-type-is-httpresponsemessage)

Answer (score 1):

Update the controller Action to have a Route attribute as below

```html
 public class ClientController : ApiController
 {
      [Route("api/Client/GeAAA/{userCode}")]    
      [HttpGet]
      public List<User> GetAAA(int userCode)
      {
         return null;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your controller Method:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<User> GetAAA(int id)
{
    return null;
}
```

Or use the url:

> http://localhost:7734/api/Client/GetAAA?userCode=1783

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a case of Convention based routing vs Attribute routing.

ASP.NET MVC will use convention based routing, as stated in your config file.

Because of this, "GET" will be dropped from the url parameter.

it should look something like this:

http://localhost:7734/api/Client/AAA/1783

I have personally found convention based routing less useful though, so I use attribute based routing (also configured in your config file).

Add this to your GetAAA method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetAAA/{userCode}")]
public List<User> GetAAA(int userCode)
{
     ...
}
```

this Route attribute should allow you to use the link as you've stated.

Comment: I do not want to work with Route... There is no change to acceted as defined in WebApiConfig? I do not why it doesnot work. It Works in others projects....

Comment: web API 2.0 does some magic. If you read some documentation on it, it will tell you that "Get" is a keyword and it will drop it from a method for the api call

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. Such a dumb I did not see it before.

My idea is not to use `[Route]`, just use how is defined in `WebApiConfig`

the definition is

```html
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

The only thing I have to do in my call

> public List GetAAA(int userCode)

is replace de parameter name....

> public List GetAAA(int id)

`id` is how is defined in the configuration...